# Can't open Raw GREY (8-bit) file

Tags: ffmpeg, v4l2, raw

I have a Raspberry Pi Zero W with the MV-MIPI-IMX264M sensor, and I'm capturing images in raw format with the specified settings. However, I cannot open these images. Any ideas on how to view these images?

[image: Screenshot1]
[image: Screenshot2]
[image: Screenshot3]
[image: Screenshot4]
[image: Screenshot5]
formats supported by the sensor (captured by qv4l2)
[image: Screenshot6]

Comment: Please do not screenshot terminal content - instead, please copy/paste the content into a code box _(please see the formatting bar or the `?` button to the far right on the formatting bar)_. When adding images, please use the _Image_ button on the formatting bar

Comment: Im pretty sure the Photos app on Windows can open RAW files.

Comment: And Darktable is available for any Linux distro that runs in a RPi.